# java.net.ConnectException while submitting job to Yarn in spark standalone mode on cent0s7

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am getting below exception while submitting a job to Yarn:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From sparkstandalone.abc.com/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I am not able to identify where the problem exactly lies.
Resource manager(Yarn) is running. Below is my yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>
 
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
 
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
 
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8033</value>
</property>
 
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8088</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Spark Standalone means it does **not** use YARN...

Comment: In any case, port 9000 is set by hdfs-site.xml, so are you running a namenode and datanode?

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 for reply. Yes i have set port 9000 is set by hdfs-site.xml but i dont see any namenode or datanode running via jps.. what can i do for it??

Comment: You'll need to run the `start-dfs.sh` script. You might want to go over some Hadoop installation guides, since the problem you currently have is unrelated to Spark